# What font is used for Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain's subtitles?

Tags: font-identification

Is anyone able to identify the font used for Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain's subtitles? 'WhatTheFont' wasn't able to narrow the search down.

Here's an example:

[image: Example of Metal Gear Solid V: The Phantom Pain's subtitles]

Comment: Didn't know I could do that. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font is called 'ニューシネマA' ('New Cinema A') by Fontworks Inc. It appears to be in widespread use in the Japanese cinema, anime, and video game industries.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how did you figure this out?

Comment: I started by searching through a bunch of Konami Japan sites for 'font' using Googles `site` property. I stumbled upon some legalese featuring the name of the typography company, 'Fontworks Inc.'. I went through their fonts individually until I found the font that matches the subtitles in MGSV: TPP, 'ニューシネマA'. I found a lot of people discussing the font on Japanese forums and chan boards with references to the font across a bunch of different media.